# Don't initiate object if exception occurs?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to prevent the initialization of a python object if an exception is catched in `__init__`?

**Example**

```
class pwm():

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            wiring_pi = cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/lib.so')
        except:
            print "Problem with loading the library:", sys.exc_info()
            #DON'T CREATE THE OBJECT, FOR IT IS USELES WITHOUT lib.so
```

Comment: And what do you expect to be returned to the caller then? What will `foo` be set to in `foo = pwm()`? Better to throw the exception!

Comment: The object has already been created by the time `__init__` is called. Instantiation happens in `__new__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can raise an exception from `__init__`, sure.  Then the caller will see the exception.  Strictly speaking, the object has been created, but it will be reclaimed when the exception is thrown because there are no references to it.

In your example code, either omit the `except` clause entirely, or raise an exception from it.

Answer (score 2):

Override `__new__` and load the dll there.  If it fails, raise an exception before the call to `super().__new__(...)` in `__new__`.

Comment: Why?  There's no advantage over doing the work in `__init__`.

Comment: You should ask the OP...  I was just suggesting a way to do what he asked. I didn't recommend doing it.

Comment: *sigh*, they're here looking for answers, it helps to give them wisdom.  If their question is slightly misguided (how do I prevent initialization), you're better off adjusting their question than simply answering it literally.

Comment: You gave "them" wisdom in your answer, which I support.  If you don't think somebody's answer is good enough, the best way to educate them is to offer a better answer. Let the OP and the community decide which answer is the most helpful.  That's the beauty of SO.  I don't see the point of criticizing other answers only for trying to answer a question directly.  I think everybody is "better off" giving the answer they think is best, instead of giving the answer they think the SO community thinks is best.  The latter would suppress the beautiful variety and diversity found here.

Comment: Your answer is stated as, "Override `__new__` ..."  You didn't include, "this has no benefit over the simpler answers elsewhere," or "I don't recommend this, but since you asked directly."  My comment was part of fleshing out this answer so that people could fully evaluate it.  Providing bare technical details with no other information doesn't give people enough to decide.

Comment: Right. _You_ included it in _your_ answer. Providing an alternative answer, like you did, _does_ give people enough to decide.  You gave a good answer.  Adding a _your-answer-should-be-more-like-mine_ type of comment is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a static methode who catch the execption in the **init** and then return None or whatever...

```
class AesSedai(object):
    def __init__(name="Moiraine"):
        wiring_pi = cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/lib.so')
    @staticmethod
    def create_wizard(cls,*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            wiring_pi = cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/lib.so')
            return cls(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print "Problem with loading the library:", sys.exc_info()
            return
```